# Azure AD B2C logout issue

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

Issue summary:
msal.logout() appears to log the user out, but after "logging out" the user can click "login" and be logged in again without being required to enter their username and password.

This is a serious security issue for user's who login to our application on a public computer, then logout thinking that they have prevented someone from accessing their account.

Frontend is using Angular-msal 1.0.0 (Angular-oauth2-oidc has the same issue, so I think it's not the problem of js library).
Azure AD B2C built in user flow and xml custom policy both have this logout issue when login with federated AAD tenant user.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSAL library provides [a logout method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript#sign-out) that clears the cache in browser storage and sends a sign-out request to Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). Request will be done against the `end_session_endpoint` URL obtained from the [B2C policy metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#validate-signature). Keep in mind [single sign out is supported only by custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-overview#sign-out) and that it's scoped to the same browser, not device.

Just in case you are still facing any issue an idea would be to redirect using `&prompt=login`in your auth url will revoke your login request with out user session.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I did use that logout method provided by MSAL library.
Also tried with &prompt=login, but still doesn't work.
Is the &prompt=login used for auth code flow? I'm using implicit flow.

Comment: ` &prompt=login`  can be used in any flow and it will force the app to go to login page

Comment: Are you using custom policies? Are you using Application scoped SSO?

Comment: I'm using custom policies and Tenant scoped SSO.

Comment: Hi @BlueArena, Is the authentication happening in webview??

Comment: I found the root cause for this issue, there is an error when do the logout: Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
This prevent to display the logout page which can let you to choose which user account want to logout. I think without this it won't send a sign-out request to Azure AD.

Comment: This is a known issue in msal.js occurs due to browser extension cookie blockers / third party cookies disabled in browsers.

To fix this, MSAL.js v2 mitigates this in most scenarios by using the auth code flow instead of the implicit flow.

Comment: Hi @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity, Thank you very much.

Comment: I found a workaround for this issue, doesn't resolve the xframe issue, but it's working.
Add "postLogoutRedirectUri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200" to the auth config.

Tried to use below logoutUrl and postLogoutRedirectUri, but not working.
"logoutUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout",
"postLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:4200/",

Comment: Have you tried changing the auth flow from implicit to auth code flow.

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity, I tried that before, seems auth code flow doesn't work with msal.js 1.0 and angular-oauth2-oidc 1.0

Comment: The MSAL library will now support the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE for Browser-Based Applications without a backend web server. Please refer [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser#implicit-flow-vs-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) for more details.